# Virus introduced in a question?

Tags: support, specific-question, code-formatting

Wanted to suggest adding some security to questions and answers whenever code added. In some weird way my Avast antivirus always complains of a trojan in the following question:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8721/o-que-o-codigo-abaixo-escrito-por-um-cracker-faz

Warning: I do not recommend entering the link if you don't have an antivirus installed.

My doubt is the following, does my antivirus recognize the php code even when not running and as such giving me a warning or will the code run even if only posted in the question?

I posted it her because I think it's a possible security treat to the whole StackOverflow/StackExchange community and if it's possible to do this in the pt.SO than it also has to be possible to pull off here and anywhere else!

## Edit:

So conclusion is that my antivirus is paranoid. However I still remain a little skeptical about the possibility, I can add markdown language and html to the answer/question so could it be possible to add a virus?

BTW . I added a beacon to the question, with markdown, just to test it and it works, it tracks the amount of views in real-time and it's invisible to the naked eye. I think I make some sort of a point. As this is just a innocent beacon normally used to track github (https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon) pages it could be something else.

Although I like this one to work! :-P It's a nice feature if only tracking is possible!

[image: GAnalytics]

Comment: It's just text.  Your anti-virus is just being paranoid.  It can't infect your computer, any more than a picture of a tiger can bite you. (That is, unless you copy and paste it into a PHP script and run it, at least.)

Comment: The question seems to be about code injected into a website.  It might be a virus, but it's PHP code, so it can't do anything.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, I tried to copy-paste a tiger into a PHP script and have been bitten as a result. I don't know, however, if it was the tiger or the script.

Comment: So paranoid antivirus? Avast doesn't usually fail though... No reason to downvote... Just concerned about the website's security... -.-'

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That one was worth a laugh! ;)

Comment: While you were right to ask here, it's a bit funny that in your "answer" to that specific question you're referring readers to a shortened URL, where people have no idea what they would be opening. (Well, adding a plus to the URL will reveal its target, if one is logged in to some Google service: http://goo.gl/o7TV5l+) Also, the images you link to are not publicly accessible; please always [use the SE provided image upload](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) instead. All that said, please remove that post; it's not answering that question.

Comment: I'm quite new and am editing while I figure things out... I used a short url because Avast's URL is to big and wasn't working somehow and used dropbox's public folder to provide the images but somehow it's not sincronizing... I am trying to put the links to work and also will try your suggestion for the images thanks!

Comment: (See also: [Replying in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply).)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100817/avast-reporting-virus-when-browsing-to-so-question

Comment: Antivirus software is afraid your browsing with internet explorer. To be honest, who isn't afraid of browsing with internet explorer?

Comment: Well, I certainly am! But it does raise the question. We are enabled to add html to our questions and answers, does that make it possible to add a script to the site and eventually run it as spyware or even as virus?

Comment: Only a tiny subset is allowed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: Like Bart already commented before you edited your question: only a tiny subset of HTML is allowed. Together with Markdown, all you can do is add formatting, `<a>` and `<img>`. No way you can abuse that to fool a browser into executing code. Adding web bug images [is just nasty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/can-we-use-non-gravatar-avatars/5658#5658) and for me would be a reason to edit them out and downvote the post.

Comment: why? I think it's useful to see what's happening to your posts, if it's abusive I kinda agree that it's a reason to downvote but otherwise... That's kinda what I question, "Is it possible to abuse this?". In other cases it can help people to have a clear overview of what's happening to their votes, because in my opinion, SO lacks of some analytics data for the user. I think it's something that helps one to improve question/answer quality as well, just like you would on a website.

Comment: Just to be clear: Don't add tracking images to your posts; this violates the terms of service (no hidden data collection allowed). See [Is it OK for me to track visits to my Stack Exchange profile, questions, & answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192201)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's just text.  It cannot infect your computer.

Your anti-virus is just being paranoid — it sees some suspicious-looking code in a web page, and it can't be 100% sure that it *won't* get executed somehow, so it warns about it.  (It also doesn't seem to be smart enough to realize that your browser isn't going to run PHP code, anyway.)

Sure, it's pretty obvious, just from looking at the code, that it's been obfuscated, and that's a pretty strong sign that it's not meant to do anything good.  But it's PHP code, intended to be run on a web server (not in a browser), and in any case what you see on the page is just the *text* of the code.

To actually make it do whatever nasty stuff it's supposed to do, you'd have to:

1. copy and paste the code into a `.php` file,
2. upload the file to a web server (with PHP support enabled),
3. visit the URL of the script that you uploaded, causing your web server to execute it.

---

**Ps.** With a bit of PHP knowledge, you can de-obfuscate the code pretty easily.*  It turns out to be a copy of the [WSO Web Shell](https://scottlinux.com/2013/04/06/wso-web-shell-php-shell-used-by-hackers/).  So it's not actually a virus, although any skript kiddy who managed to upload it to your web server and run it could use it as a "back door" to do all sorts of stuff there.

<sup>*) First, prepend `echo` to the last line, remove the `e` from `/.*/e` and run it (as an unprivileged user in a sandbox, of course); the output will be more obfuscated PHP code, but replacing the (two!) `eval` calls with `print` before running it (again, in a sandbox, just in case) will reveal the actual code.</sup>

Comment: I just followed your 3 step plan and now everything has stopped working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As for that last part: how's your Portuguese? Seems like this would make a good answer to that question :-)

Comment: @Arjan: Pretty awful. I can barely order a beer and ask for directions to the bathroom.